# Error Estimate for f(x,y) using trapezoidal rule

Tags: approximate-integration

Please I need help.  How do I find the error estimate of the trapezoidal rule of the function
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2}}{1+y^{3}}dy
$$
using
$$
-\frac{h^{2}}{12}[f'(b)-f'(a)]
$$
where $$x,y\in(0,1)$$
I know the formula, the confusing part is finding $f'(b)$ and $f'(a)$. I was thinking $f'(x_{b},y_{b}) = f'(1,1)$ and $f'(x_{a},y_{a}) = f'(0,0)$. Please if  I am wrong, correct me.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Hint: $x$ is a constant in the integral, so it's not changing (i.e., not $x_a$ and $x_b$), and also the derivative is wrt just $y$.

Comment: yeah the derivative is wrt to just y, so if x is not changing, what then will be the value of x in f'(b) and f'(a) since x is within (0,1). Thanks.

Comment: Note that $f$ is a function of *only* the variable $y$, i.e., $f(y) = \frac{x^2}{1 + y^3}$. As I stated, $x$ is treated as being a *constant* parameter, so its value in $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ will be just $x$, i.e., some undetermined value in $(0,1)$. In particular, note your error estimate will end up being a function of $x$, i.e., it won't be a constant.

Comment: Thanks so much. I get it now. So can I apply this same idea to an integral equation with kernel similiar to this equation?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you understand this now. However, although I think I know, I'm not completely sure if I understand what you mean by "kernel". Note the basic concept, of course, applies to other integrals where there's one or more variables which aren't being integrated. If you have anything else to ask regarding this, or anything else, which is not part of this current question, I suggest you ask a new question about it.